# Save variables in a loop after reading them out of a .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

## My problem

Below you can see my commented solution.

I read in a folder with all text files.
After that I want to use a loop to read in all files and their contents as variables. I do this with it.
Since I unfortunately have a German based text file I have to rewrite it to be able to continue working with it.
Then I convert the created list into an array.
At the end of the loop I get only the last text file as variable.
But I want to have a variable or an array for each text file.

`data[0]` are the values from the text file 0.

`data[1]` are the values from the text file 1.

`data[2]` are the values from text file 2.

and so on.

I know that something is missing at the end of the loop, but I just don't know what to do.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

read_files = glob.glob('*.txt')

for i in range(0, len(read_files):
    temp = []
    data = []

    txt_file = open(read_files[i], 'r+').readlines()[1:]

    for line in txt_file:
        line = line.replace(',', '.')
        line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
        line = line.replace('****', '0')
        temp.append(line)

    temp = np.array(temp)
    data = np.loadtxt(temp)
    print(data)
```

My approaches were:

1. Writing a matrix and rewriting all values from the variable *data* with two loops.
2. Define `data` as a run variable.
3. Write a new file and read it in again. Works, but is cumbersome and costs too much memory.

## My solution

I have now defined a function `convert` so that all text files in the subfolder are converted.

```
def convert(path):
    # Read the path of the text files
    txtfiles = []
    for file in glob.glob(str(path)+'/*.txt'):
        txtfiles.append(file)

    for i in range(len(txtfiles)):
        # Create empty lists and overwrite them in every loop step.
        temp = []
        data = []
        data_temp = []
        
        # Read in the text file on position i out of the list txtfiles and skip the header.
        txt_file = open(txtfiles[i], 'r+').readlines()[1:]
        ## Optional: If there is no header take the line below
        #txt_file = open(txtfiles[i], 'r+')
          
        # Replacing symbols in the text file
        for line in txt_file:
            # Replace comma through dot
            line = line.replace(',', '.')
            # Replace tabulator through space
            line = line.replace('\t', ' ')      
            # Replace **** through zeros
            line = line.replace('****', '0')  
            # Write converted lines into new list
            temp.append(line)

        # Create a temporary list with the input data
        data.append(temp)                       

        ## Optional: Delete variables to save memory
        #del txt_file, temp
        
        # Create array and read list 
        data_temp = np.array(data[0])
        # Read the array as a .txt file   
        data_temp = np.loadtxt(data_temp)

        ## Optional: Save into new .txt file
        np.savetxt('new_file.txt', data_temp, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: why don't you use `for filename in read_files:`

Comment: The reason you got only the content of the last files is because you override the variable data at the end of every loop. If you want to memorize the content of all files, define data outside the outer for loop, and append the result of np.loadtxt to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need one more list. This will be list of lists. Something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

read_files = glob.glob('*.txt')

all_data = []
for i in range(0, len(read_files):
    temp = []
    
    txt_file = open(read_files[i], 'r+').readlines()[1:]

    for line in txt_file:
        line = line.replace(',', '.')
        line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
        line = line.replace('****', '0')
        temp.append(line)

    all_data.append(temp)
    
print(all_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot. I also worked on it. The list 'all_data' is now in the loop so that it overwritten with every file the loop reads. It is to not fill the memory with a giant matrix.